# Creating animations for Unity models using Blender?

Tags: unity

I am relatively new to Unity.

Currently, I am trying to make some animations using the free model Unity-Chan available from the asset store. Could someone post some helpful tips or perhaps a link with a brief walkthrough on how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple:

1. First export your model from unity: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjExporter
2. Next, Import it into blender:
   [image]
3. Add animations using the rigging tools
4. Export FBX to unity using these settings:

[image]

Done!